# How to query connected Ethernet device for MAC address

Tags: ethernet

Is there a way to query connected devices through the Ethernet protocol? i.e. I would like to broadcast an Ethernet frame (destination ff:ff:ff:ff) so that it is received by my device B connected via ethernet, and then have the device B respond with literally anything, so I can intercept the incoming Ethernet packet (e.g. via Wireshark) and thus find out the MAC address of the device.

Both devices are disconnected from the Internet and only connected to each other via an Ethernet cable, to make tracking easier.

The issue is I do not know what to put in my Ethernet broadcast frame so that it will elicit a response from device B.

Comment: do the machines have IP addresses? if so, ARP would do it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol

Comment: Yeah true, unfortunately the only possible way to do this is with IP support. This PIC32 device does not support IP but there is software from the manufacturer that has methods to get the MAC.